# Compress Plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compression, plist

Apple will always compress the plist file in our project build file (.ipa/.app) into binary plist format.
which is still contains some string which is in readable formate.

Here I want to follow some other compression mechanism  which will compress my plist files in 011100 something like this formate.

My question is is it possible to do this in xcode project if yes how to do that and which method i should follow to compress my plist files..??

Thanks in advance....